# Fragments in ViewPager2 not filling height

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager, fragment

I have setup ViewPager2 with TabLayout in order to switch fragments with a swipe or clicking on the tabs. The problem I have know is that my fragments are not taking all the space and I have an empty space at the bottom where I cannot swipe. How can I make my fragments to fill that space?

Edit: I think that my problem is related with the fact that I'm trying to load my viewpager inside another fragment. I copied my code into a new project and instead of loading my code into a fragment I loaded it into the main activity and It has worked. Is it a bad practice to load viewpagers inside a fragment?

I've changed my **ProfileFragment.kt** like this but it is still not working:

```
class ProfileFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var tabsText: List<String>
    private val adapter by lazy {
        ViewPagerAdapter(childFragmentManager, lifecycle)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        tabsText = listOf<String>(getString(R.string.user_info),
            getString(R.string.saved_recipes), getString(R.string.shopping_list))
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        pager.adapter = adapter

        TabLayoutMediator(tabs, pager) { tab, position ->
            tab.text = tabsText.get(position)
        }.attach()
    }
}

class ViewPagerAdapter(manager: FragmentManager, lifecycle: Lifecycle): FragmentStateAdapter(manager, lifecycle) {
    override fun getItemCount(): Int = 3

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment = when(position) {
        0 -> UserInfoFragment.newInstance()
        1 -> SavedRecipesFragment.newInstance()
        else -> ShoppingListFragment.newInstance()
    }
}
```

**fragment_profile.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"/>

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**ProfileFragment.kt**

```
class ProfileFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var tabsText: List<String>
    private val adapter by lazy {
        ViewPagerAdapter(this)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        tabsText = listOf<String>(getString(R.string.user_info),
            getString(R.string.saved_recipes), getString(R.string.shopping_list))
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)


        pager.adapter = adapter

        TabLayoutMediator(tabs, pager) { tab, position ->
            tab.text = tabsText.get(position)
        }.attach()
    }
}

class ViewPagerAdapter(fragment: Fragment): FragmentStateAdapter(fragment) {
    override fun getItemCount(): Int = 3

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment = when(position) {
        0 -> UserInfoFragment.newInstance()
        1 -> SavedRecipesFragment.newInstance()
        else -> ShoppingListFragment.newInstance()
    }
}
```

One of the fragments that I'm loading has this xml:
**fragment_user_info.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_account_circle_black_56dp"
        android:text="@string/username" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/init_info_age"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/username_text"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:hint="@string/age"
        app:helperTextEnabled="true"
        app:helperText="@string/fui_required_field">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/init_info_age_editText"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:layout_below="@id/init_info_age">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/profile_info_height"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"

            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:hint="@string/height"
            app:helperTextEnabled="true"
            app:helperText="@string/fui_required_field"
            >

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/profile_info_height_editText"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/profile_info_weight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:hint="@string/weight"
            app:helperTextEnabled="true"
            app:helperText="@string/fui_required_field"
            >

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/profile_info_weight_editText"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:layout_below="@id/linear_layout1">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/profile_gender"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
            android:hint="@string/gender"
            >

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/autocomplete_view_gender"
                android:labelFor="@id/profile_gender"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/profile_lifestyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
            android:hint="@string/activity"
            >

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/autocomplete_view_lifestyle"
                android:labelFor="@id/profile_gender"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/edit"
        android:layout_below="@id/linear_layout2"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Image of the fragment and the empty space]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your ViewPager's height is set to `wrap_content` so it's height is as small as possible. Try setting it to `0dp` and setting `android:layout_weight="1"`.

You also may want to use ConstraintLayout instead of LinearLayout. Try:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tabs" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This will make your `ViewPager` height from the bottom of the TabLayout to the bottom of parent layout.

I got this result from your example code (I had to mock your fragments, and string resources) combined with my ConstraintLayout xml:

[image]

Comment: If I set it to match_parent the fragments cover the tabs.

Comment: After applying your changes my fragments are not visible now. I don't understand why it's happening as your suggestion made sense to me.

Comment: Did you use `android:layout_height="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="1"` within LinearLayout or `android:layout_height="0dp"`
        `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`
        `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tabs"` within ConstraintLayout? Can you post how your layout xml looks now?

Comment: I pasted your entire code and remove mine from the xml file.

Comment: I also applied the changes in linear layout you mention and that give the same result that I had at the start. Maybe viewpager don't behave as a normal layout. It's my first time using it, I don't really know.

Comment: This must be something different in your app. I used the code that you provided, and for xml used my ConstraintLayout layout from the answer above. And it works just fine.

Comment: I've added the xml of one of the fragments that I'm trying to load, the one in the screenshot. Maybe it has something to do with that.

Comment: I created an example project: https://github.com/aleksandra-majchrzak/so_viewPager

Comment: Please read my post again, I added an edit section. I think I've discovered why this is not working for me but I'm stuck fixing it.

Comment: I updated my example with your updated code. It still works. I'm not sure what you meant in your edit. Is `ProfileFragment` embedded in a different Fragment or Acitivity? If a different fragment, than the size of that fragment also matters.

Comment: I have an activity with navigation implemented, so everything are fragments. Now, in my ProfileFragment I'm triying to load the ViewPager, so at then end I have nested fragments.

Comment: So the problem was that in my main_activity xml file I had the fragment height set to wrap content. Rookie mistake :D. Thanks a lot.

Comment: All after all you had multiple problems, so my answer altogether with comments was correct. It would be very nice of you, if you'd accept my answer :)

Comment: This is amazing. I searched for 6 hours, asked ChatGPT4 many times, still cannot find a solution. For example, virtual keyboard show and dismiss, the view cannot resized to normal size, then all searches just pointing to `SoftInputMode`. Using Linear Layout and height="match_parent" to fill remaining space, No problem in ViewPager but do not work in ViewPager2. `android:layout_height="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="1" ` really solve the issue! thanks~